# Python program not working - simple mathematic function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

```
cat Prog4CCM.py
numberArray = []
count = 0

#filename = input("Please enter the file name: ") 
filename = "t.txt" # for testing purposes
file = open(filename, "r")


for each_line in file:
    numberArray.append(each_line)



for i in numberArray:
    print(i)
    count = count + 1

        
    
def findMaxValue(numberArray, count):
    maxval = numberArray[0]
    for i in range(0, count):
        if numberArray[i] > maxval:
            maxval = numberArray[i]
    return maxval


def findMinValue(numberArray, count):
    minval = numberArray[0]
    for i in range(0, count):
        if numberArray[i] < minval:
            minval = numberArray[i]
    return minval


def findFirstOccurence(numberArray, vtf, count):
    for i in range(0, count):
        if numberArray[i] == vtf:
            return i
            break
        i = i + 1


# Function calls start


print("The maxiumum value in the file is "+ str(findMaxValue(numberArray, count)))
print("The minimum value in the file is "+str(findMinValue(numberArray, count)))

vtf = input("Please insert the number you would like to find the first occurence of: ")
print("First occurence is at "+str(findFirstOccurence(numberArray, vtf, count)))
```

This is supposed to call a function (Find First Occurrence) and check for the first occurrence in my array.

It should return a proper value, but just returns "None". Why might this be?

The file reading, and max and min value all seem to work perfectly.

Comment: It looks like the `findFirstOccurence` function is missing a return statement at the end. As a result, when the function reaches the end of its execution, it returns `None` by default. To fix this issue, you can add a return statement at the end of the `findFirstOccurence` function that returns a default value, such as -1, `return -1`.

Comment: You're also trying to assign to your loop variable.  Don't do that, it makes no sense.  The value is just going to be overwritten at the top of the loop anyway.  To be specific, delete the line `i = i + 1` from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a return in the `findFirstOccurence()` function, in case the vtf response is not in the list and there is an error with adding one to the iterator and use break, the for loop will do that for you.

The correct code would look like this:

```py
...

def findFirstOccurence(numberArray, vtf, count):
    for i in range(0, count):
        if numberArray[i] == vtf:
            return i
        #     break # <==
        # i = i + 1 # It's errors
    return "Can't find =("


# Function calls start


print("The maxiumum value in the file is "+ str(findMaxValue(numberArray, count)))
print("The minimum value in the file is "+str(findMinValue(numberArray, count)))

vtf = input("Please insert the number you would like to find the first occurence of: ")
print("First occurence is at "+str(findFirstOccurence(numberArray, vtf, count)))
```

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, the function `findFirstOccurence` miss **return** statement. If you want us to help you debug the code in detail, you may need to provide your test data, like `t.txt`